# Iterate through nested json object array

Tags: javascript, json

I have to iterate through json array object.

It has following structure.

```
var myJSONObject = {
    "abc": {
        "prod_1": [
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 1"},
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 2"},
        ],
        "prod_2": [
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 1"},
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 2"},
        ],
        "prod_3": [
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 3 ver 1"},
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 3 ver 2"},
        ]
    }
};
```

Basically what I am doing is prod_1 is name of a product and the list of versions that prod_1 has are populated inside it.

So now what i want is the name of the product as well as what versions it has.

The problem is there can be many products and many versions under that product.
So i need a proper looping structure in **javascript** that can be generic to handle it.

It would be best if the loop stores product name in one var and it's version in another var as there are some checking i need to on product name.

If the json structure is wrong or a better json structure can be written the please suggest a right/better structure.

Please **HELP**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <obligatory>That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object initializer</obligatory>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `myJSONObject.abc` contains a list of products it would make more sense to define the property `abc` as an array. Like this:

```
var myJSONObject = 
{
"abc":
    [
        [
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 1"},
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 2"},
        ],
        [
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 1"},
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 2"},
        ],
        [
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 3 ver 1"},
            {"prod_ver" : "prod 3 ver 2"},
        ]
    ]
};
```

Then you can iterate over the products and their versions using normal loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myJSONObject.abc.length; i++)
{
    var product = myJSONObject.abc[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < product.length; j++)
    {
        var version = product[j];
    }
}
```

You could take it slightly further and alter your JSON object's structure a bit to make it more easily understandable.

```
var catalog = 
{
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "prod 1",
            "versions": [
                "ver 1",
                "ver 2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "prod 2",
            "versions": [
                "ver 1",
                "ver 2"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

for(var i = 0; i < catalog.products.length; i++)
{
    var product = catalog.products[i];
    var productName = product.name;
    for(var j = 0; j < product.versions.length; j++)
    {
        var version = product.versions[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: **Thanx** the solution with catalog object seems to be better.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. How could I do this if I don't know the key names (ie: "products" "names" or "versions")?

Comment: I recommend creating a new question and sharing an example of your data, so you can be helped better.

Answer (score 8):

`myJSONObject.abc` is an object with keys like `prod_1`, `prod_2`, etc. You can loop through the keys of an object using `for-in`. So:

```
var productName;
var productVersionArray;

for (productName in myJSONObject.abc) {
    productVersionArray = myJSONObject.abc[productName];
}
```

Note that the order of the keys is not defined by the specification and will vary from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine. If you want to do them in a particular order, you have to get an array of them, sort it in the order you want, and then loop through that array. (In an ES5-enabled environment, you can get an array of the keys of an object from `Object.keys(yourObject)`. But you'd need a shim for older browsers.)

Within that loop, you can loop through the array using a standard `for` loop:

```
for (versionIndex = 0; versionIndex < productVersionArray.length; ++versionIndex) {
    // Use `productVersionArray[versionIndex].prod_ver` here
}
```

Here's an example putting it all together:

```
(function() {

  var myJSONObject = 
    {
    "abc":
        {
            "prod_1": 
            [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 1"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 1 ver 2"}
            ],

            "prod_2": 
            [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 1"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 2 ver 2"}
            ],
            "prod_3": 
            [
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 3 ver 1"},
                {"prod_ver" : "prod 3 ver 2"}
            ]
        }
    };

  var productName;
  var productVersionArray;
  var versionIndex;

  for (productName in myJSONObject.abc) {
      productVersionArray = myJSONObject.abc[productName];
      display(productName + " has " + productVersionArray.length + " versions listed");
      for (versionIndex = 0; versionIndex < productVersionArray.length; ++versionIndex) {
        display("* " + productVersionArray[versionIndex].prod_ver);
      }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

})();
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uyagoc/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uyagoc/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Updated with ES6

```
  var { products } =
    {
        "products": [
            {
                "name": "prod 1",
                "versions": [
                    "ver 1",
                    "ver 2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "prod 2",
                "versions": [
                    "ver 1",
                    "ver 2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "prod 3",
                "versions": [
                    "ver 1",
                    "ver 2"
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    let inventory = products.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        let { name, versions } = currentValue;
        accumulator[name] = versions
        return accumulator
    }, []);

    Object.entries(inventory).forEach((prod) => {
        let prodName = prod[0];
        let prodVers = prod[1].join(", ");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function z() {
  for (let key in myJSONObject.abc) {
    let value = myJSONObject.abc[key];
    for (let i = 0; i <= value.length; i++) {
      console.log(value[[i]]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context/explanation to it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.