# Tableau json API WebConnector

Tags: javascript, json, api, iterator, tableau-api

I've written the following tableau webconnector to pull data from an internal API, using earthquakeUSGS.html as a guideline (https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector). The API returns json (see code below). I've been using the "Web data connector simulator 2.0" and all has been going well. I get the correct Table, however, Im unable to "Fetch Table Data". As this is my first js script, Im very sure that is were the error is. To iterate through the data I used the answer from Korijn in this post [Iterate through nested json object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268594/iterate-through-nested-json-object-array)

**The Problem**: Is probably with the js iterator over the json object. If anyone can take a look at the json (below), and have a look at my iterator, I would greatly appreciate it. This is what makes it impossible for me to fetch data.

**test.js**

```
(function() {
    // Create the connector object
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    // Define the schema
    myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
        var cols = [{
            id: "prog",
            alias: "PrognosisTime",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "start",
            alias: "Start",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.date
        }, {
            id: "val",
            alias: "Value",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float
        }];

        var tableSchema = {
            id: "table",
            alias: "187",
            columns: cols
        };

        schemaCallback([tableSchema]);
    };

    // Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        $.getJSON("http://myapi.com/119%2C7777/Flattened?start=today&end=today&timeZone=CET&asOf=now&aggregation=None", function(resp) {
            var feat = resp.features,
                tableData = [];
                tableData.push(
                    {"table":feat.properties.table}
                    );

            // Iterate over the JSON object
            //var SeriesId = feat.SeriesId
            for(var i = 0; i <feat.DataPoints.length; i++){
                var PrognosisTime = feat.DataPoints.PrognosisTime;
                var Start = feat.DataPoints.Start;
                var Value = feat.DataPoints.Value;
            }
            table.appendRows(tableData);
            doneCallback();
        });
    };

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);

    // Create event listeners for when the user submits the form
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitButton").click(function() {
            tableau.connectionName = "Neas"; // This will be the data source name in Tableau
            tableau.submit(); // This sends the connector object to Tableau
        });
    });
})();
```

**json from API**

```
[
  {
    "SeriesId": 119,
    "DataPoints": [
      {
        "PrognosisTime": null,
        "Start": "2016-08-24T00:00:00",
        "Value": 26.19
      },
      {
        "PrognosisTime": null,
        "Start": "2016-08-24T01:00:00",
        "Value": 23.9
      },
      {
        "PrognosisTime": null,
        "Start": "2016-08-24T02:00:00",
        "Value": 22.82
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "SeriesId": 7777,
    "DataPoints": [
      {
        "PrognosisTime": null,
        "Start": "2016-08-24T00:00:00",
        "Value": 36.39
      },
      {
        "PrognosisTime": null,
        "Start": "2016-08-24T00:15:00",
        "Value": 28.81
      },
      {
        "PrognosisTime": null,
        "Start": "2016-08-24T00:30:00",
        "Value": 24.28
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var feat = resp.features
```

resp is an array from your JSON, there is nothing called features. So, simply iterate over resp (or feat = resp) and pull out your DataPoints array.